# how to multiply pandas pandas data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

im a beginner.

I have a python dataframe as below.  I would like to multiply each of the elements by a=100, b=200, c=300. Can someone help me to understand how to do that?

There are n number of columns.

Thank you.

| index | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 22 | 20 | 18 |
| 2021-01-02 | 25 | 29 | 7 |
| 2021-01-03 | 15 | 30 | 20 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary and apply operation to your dataframe:

```
coeff = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300}

df.update(df[coeff.keys()].mul(pd.Series(coeff), axis=1))
```

```
>>> df
        index     a     b     c
0  2021-01-01  2200  4000  5400
1  2021-01-02  2500  5800  2100
2  2021-01-03  1500  6000  6000
```

Alternative with a list:

```
df[['a', 'b', 'c']] *= [100, 200, 300]
```

Comment: yes thank you that is perfect.  I'm very thankful for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Saying your dataframe is called `df` then it is simple as (if I understand it correctly):

```
df.a = df.a * 100
df.b = df.b * 200
df.c = df.c * 300
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  There are n number of columns though.  Ideally, can a = 100, b=200, c=300 be in a list, array, tuple, df...

Comment: You mean the values from 100 to 300 should be a list?
`listed = [100,200,300]`
Then you can just pick whichever number you need by: `listed[0]` or `listed[1]` or `listed[ 2]`.

Comment: Youre answer was correct.  thank you for your help.  creating a dictionary and using mul or multiply is more sustainable for my code.  Thank you again.